# Request to host production.local failed: parse error. not well formed (error code -32700)

Tags: php, wordpress

Yes, as above the full error log is:

```
[Wed Apr 12 15:36:58.036443 2017] [:error] [pid 964:tid 1328] [client 127.0.0.1:55360] [SME] Request to host production.local failed: parse error. not well formed (error code -32700), referer: http://staging.local/cms/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sme-edit-batch&id=24
```

I'm trying to send data from `staging.local` to `production.local` where both domains are local using:

> Content Staging plugin

Does anyone have any clues on how to debug it?

OK, I think the original message comes from `/wp-includes/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php`.

I set in `functions.php` on *both* domains:

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
```

and refresh the browser with `http://staging.local/cms/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sme-preflight-batch&id=24` the browser hangs for a while whith message `transport error: http_request_failed cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 60000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received - on host: production.local (error code -32300)` returned to screen? But I just set cURL timeout to infinity with the zero flag?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to do with my environment, in particular `php.ini`.

Setting `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` now solves this.